# How to match columns title with columns contains and reflet the values?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame like the following:

[image]

I need to keep some values matching the column's title which contains one extra column.

Could you please suggest the solution?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution:

```py
# Building of a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"index":["B","D","C","A"]}).groupby(["index"]).count()
df["value"] = None
# Function to fill the matching column
def match(index, column):
    if(index==column):
        return 1
    else:
        return ""
# Create the matching column and fill it with the right value
for index in df.index.array:
    df[index] = df.apply(lambda row: match(row.name, index), axis=1)
# Print the result dataframe
print(df)
```